# How to remove database col if viewmodel does not contains id

Tags: c#

I have a view model like below

```cs
public class UpdateRModel
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<UpdateVModel> Vs { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateVModel
{
    public int id {get;set;}
}
```

What I am trying to do is
my database table (version) has three rows.
after edit one row deleted and now two row exits.

old ids
1,2,3

new ids
1,3

now I want to remove 2 in database that is not exit in view model .

I tried something like below

```cs
var result // this is my database returned value 
foreach (var newItem in viewModel.Vs )
{
    foreach (var table.id in result.table  )
    {
        if(newItem.Find(table.id) != null)
        {
            //remove
        }
    }
}
```

if there any possible way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM the ViewModel is the intermediary layer between your View (UI) and your Model (database).

You've highlighted one of the issues that you must contend with when it comes to keeping the View Model and the Model in synchronisation.

You're View Model must be able to cope with errors in making changes to the database.

In this case you should delete the record from the database and if successful then delete the View Model from your View Model List. That way you are showing a real representation of the database contents.

Similarly, when editing records you need to allow for the possibility that a record isn't updated successfully and thus you must notify the user and roll the View Model back to what the database actually has.